# How do javascript functions work? specifically arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that has an ajax call. On callback it uses an argument to find a class. If I call this function multiple times, will it affect the callback argument of previous functions? As in overwrite the arguments.

Example.

```
function foo(ARG){
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "www.example.com",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data){
      ARG.append(data);
    },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    }
  });
}

var class1 = $('.class1');
foo(class1);

var class2 = $('.class2');
foo(class2);

var class3 = $('.class3');
foo(class3);
```

Edit: Typically, all 3 of the functions will be called before any callbacks are made. Are the callbacks going to be using the latest version of the argument? Or the argument that was there when it was called?

Comment: So how about you try it first?

Comment: I would recommend you read up on closures.

Comment: @Justinas I've tried it and I haven't seen any issues. But I'm still not sure how they work or where I can find information about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote JS book Speaking  JavaScript By: Axel Rauschmayer

> Functions Stay Connected to Their Birth Scopes

```js
function createInc(startValue) {
    return function (step) {
        startValue += step;
        return startValue;
    };
}
var inc = createInc(5);
var inc2 = createInc(5);
console.log(inc(1));
console.log(inc(2));
console.log(inc2(1));
```

The function returned by createInc() does not lose its connection to startValue—the variable provides the function with state that persists across function calls. The book even explains the entire working in a pretty elaborate way.

Answer (score 2):

The `ARG` will not get overwritten, if that was your fear. Below is the proof.

```js
var myData = 'q=roses';

function foo(ARG) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "JSON",
    complete: function(data) {
      console.log(ARG.selector);
      ARG.append(ARG.selector);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {}
  });
}

var class1 = $('.class1');
foo(class1);

var class2 = $('.class2');
foo(class2);

var class3 = $('.class3');
foo(class3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="class1">1</p>
<p class="class2">2</p>
<p class="class3">3</p>
```